# PHP PDO How to Get ID Out of Database By Using URL

Tags: php, pdo

I've searched a bunch for this question but I'm not finding an answser. I'm new to PHP, creating a simple CRUD app using PDO. But I have an empty id from my SQL query. I'm trying to use the $_GET super global to pull the id from the database out of the URL so that I can retrieve the proper data to populate my form `value="<?php echo $row['item'] ?>`". But since the id is blank, I just get an undefined index error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is what I have tried.

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $item = $_POST['item'];
        $itemPrice = $_POST['item_price'];
        
        try {
            $sql = "UPDATE grocery_list SET item = :item, item_price = :item_price WHERE id = :id";
            $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $statement->execute(array(":item" => $item, ":item_price" => $itemPrice));
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo "An error occurred " . $ex->getMessage();
        }
        
    } else {
        echo "id is empty";
    }
```

Comment: you are not filling the `:id` in your $sql variable

Comment: where you are receiving the "undefined index error"?

Comment: What does the query URL looks like?

Comment: I get the error inside the inputs. If I hardcode the id, it works just fine. But I'm trying to get it out of the URL. I guess getting the id out of the database would work as well. Any ideas?

Comment: @KeyuGan - I also tried this to retrieve the info. ```$sql = "SELECT * FROM grocery_list WHERE id = :id";```

Answer (score 1):

*Try this ,*

```
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
                $id = $_GET['id'];
                $item = $_POST['item'];
                $itemPrice = $_POST['item_price'];
                
                try {
                    $sql = "UPDATE grocery_list SET item = :item, item_price = :item_price WHERE id = :id";
                    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                    $statement->execute(array(":item" => $item, ":item_price" => $itemPrice,":id" => $id));
                } catch (Exception $ex) {
                    echo "An error occurred " . $ex->getMessage();
                }
                
    } else {
                echo "id is empty";
    }
```

Comment: I tried this code, but still can not get the id to populate with anything. I've tried a $_POST as well. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure id is send from form ? how to send id from frontend?

Comment: The id auto increments in the database upon creating an item. This part works and gives me a unique id (number) upon entry. I really just want to get an item by the id, so I can populate the value of the edit form, then edit the item

Comment: So you should check select query for item and make sure really id is include in form and send to backend.